# Merging two different polygons to single polygon

Tags: qgis, polygon, merge, dissolve, singlepart

I have a raw data with number of polygons and sub polygons in it. Attached Snap is an example.

[image]

I can simply merge two polygons by selecting both. But i can't do that to the huge data. Is there any way to make it dissolve the smallest one in largest one.

Comment: What language / tools / library are you using?  How is the polygon defined?

Comment: Hi Mr R, im using Merge tool by selecting two polygons manually. Polygon is defined by pincode

Comment: Can you post a sample of the raw data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming all the small polygons are located inside the large polygons as you posted in your question, select those small polygons, and use [`'Eliminate Selected polygon'`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#eliminate-selected-polygons) located under the Processing toolbox (you can search for the tool), and then select the option `Merge Selection with the neighbouring polygon with the` *Largest Area*

[image]

Comment: Thanks!!! for your solution its working good.....